# A functional C++ program that doesn't use these characters: ';'. '{', '}', '\'

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, program-entry-point

This is a problem that was given at a regional contest last year. Basically, you need to make a simple program in C++ that can print the result of several strings of the format(digit, operator, digit), until EOF is reached. The operators are the usual +, -, *, \.

For example

```
3+5
2+2
4*3
9/3
```

Results in

```
8 4 12 3
```

The catch is obviously that I can't use the characters ; {  } \

I tried something like this (it just adds 2 integers but that's not the focus)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define dummy ;
#define slashDummy '\\'
#define curlDummy {
#define curlDummy2 }
using namespace std dummy


int main() curlDummy
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false) dummy
    cin.tie(0) dummy
    int x = 4 dummy
    int y = 5 dummy
    int c = x + y dummy
    cout << c dummy
    return 0 dummy
curlDummy2
```

But by using the characters in the #define I fail the task. However, if I try to replace { with char(123), the compiler won't run it (I figured it out in the end). This means that this approach is completely wrong.

I also tried to #define everything, but I soon realized that I'm not that good of a programmer and I don't know what I am doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#define bAcc char(123)
#define rAcc char(125)
#define div char(92)
#define smcolon char(59)
#define unite2(a, b) a##b
#define unite3(a, b, c) a##b##c
#define Acc unite2(bAcc, rAcc)
#define program "while(cin.get()) if(int a = 'a') if(char b = 'b') if(int c = 'c') while(std::cin >> a && a != EOF && std::cin >> b && std::cin >> c) if(b == '+' && std::cout << a + c << std::endl) Acc else if(b == '-' && std::cout << a - c << std::endl) Acc else if(b == '*' && std::cout << a * c << std::endl) Acc else if(b == char(47) && std::cout << a char(47) c << std::endl) Acc"
#define run unite3(bAcc, program, rAcc)

int main() run
```

The main function won't let me progress with this task, I tried to circumvent it but it always require { }.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Useful ref [Digraphs_and_trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs).

Comment: `;` is the only tricky part.

Comment: Write code in Python that would write code in C++, compile it and run it?

Comment: I tried cheating with a full width semicolon (`；`) ... No go ... :-)

Comment: Perhaps something like `int main(void)  {

}` with di/tri-graph subs?

Comment: Yup I solved it like this, thanks everyone :D https://pastebin.com/45gRcSCj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigraphs and if statements could achieve this.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main(void)
??<
        if (std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false))
        if (std::cin.tie(0)) ??< ??>
        if (int x = 4) ??<
                if (int y = 5) ??<
                        if (int c = x + y) ??<
                                if (std::cout << c << std::endl) ??< ??>
                        ??>
                ??>
        ??>
??>
```

Compile with -trigraphs flag.

Comment: trigraphs were removed in C++17

Comment: Digraphs and trigraphs fails when it comes to  `;`

Comment: This code compiles and prints "9" to stdin. If I must use C++17 then the question is trickier.

Comment: `if (int c = x + y)` is going to fail if `x + y` winds up being `0`.

Comment: I fixed your typos, so it'll compile. It does avoid `;` by nesting everything … So, I suppose it (mostly) works and is valid. Now try with C++17 for fun ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver that's true. You could always add "|| 1" to the if statements.

Comment: @nraiha How would you do that?  You can't have a condition if you declare a variable.  Well, unless you are using C++17 which doesn't allow trigraphs.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah that's true. I had a brain fart when thinking about that. However, the examples did not have any zeroes so there could be more clarification on that part.

Comment: @NathanOliver Could it be done with `else if(int c = x + y + 1) if(std::cout << c - 1)`?

Comment: Use digraphs instead of trigraphs and you have a solution that works with C++17 as well.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It's tricky.  On the surface that will work great, but in general it is not a solution. I don't know what data types the OP is actually using in their challenge but if they have to deal with floating points at all, it could give you an incorrect answer if `a` and `b` are sufficiently small or large.

Comment: Or you can cheat a bit and compile both trigraphs and C++17. GCC doesn't even cough when you give it `-std=c++17` and `-trigraphs` together: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y5FUzbZG82xI6u99

Comment: To remove the need for `;` perhaps something like `#define initdo(x,y) if(x)<%if(y)<%%>%>else if(y)<%%>` could work?

Comment: Turns out ; and \ were red herrings, I only needed { and } and converted them to digraphs(learnt something new today). Also the numbers are all single digits, no more advanced stuff required. Thank you guys :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the digraphs <% and %> instead of { and }.

Comment: What about `;`?  Also there is no digraph for \

Comment: @NathanOliver What do you need them for? { and } are necessary to define the "main" function.

Comment: @FlatAssembler: "The catch is obviously that I can't use the characters ; { } \"

Comment: As far as I know, you can always use a comma instead of a semi-colon in C++ except in for-loops, and you can use while-loops instead. What do you need '\' for?

Comment: *As far as I know, you can always use a comma instead of a semi-colon* Not really.  You can't do `int foo, double bar`

Comment: @FlatAssembler: Please show us a working "hello world" program with no semicolon.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be replacing he lexical `{}` with another lexical convention meaning the same for the program?

Comment: Didn't know about these things, thank you, I finally solved the problem :D